# YPImagePicker sheet navigation bar is transparent

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, navigationbar

When I open up YPImagePicker sheet to take or choose images both tab's (photo, library) navigation bars and their buttons are transparent showing buttons of parent view's navigation bar.

Parent View

[image]

YPImagePicker View (camera)
[image]

YPImagePicker View (library)
[image]

What I want is that if YPImagePicker view is visible only buttons from it's navigation bar are be visible and not from parent's view too.
I did not change any settings in YPImageView configuration, maybe there are some options to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it is problem connected with version 4.5.0 of YPImagePicker running on iOS 15 only. Updating the framework to the newest version fixed the bug.